# Shiny won't run apps

Tags: r, shiny

When I try to run any shiny app with `runApp(shinyapp(ui = ui, server=server))`, internet explorer opens and tries to visit the address `http://127.0.0.1:7254/` but then gives the error `This page can’t be displayed. Make sure the web address http://127.0.0.1:7254 is correct.`

My R terminal says it is correctly hosting the app, displaying `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7254` .

What does this mean? Is R successfully hosting the app at the address, but maybe my windows firewall is blocking me from visiting that address?

Comment: I hope you find something, but I suspect there is little we can do without more context, information, and such. "Firewall" sounds like a possible culprit, but it could be several things. (And since in my experience windows can occasionally do some funky things with 127.0.0.0/8, I can't rule out other problems, too.)

Comment: Did you try to change your default browser or the port ? With for example `options(browser = "path_to_new_browser.exe")` or `shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(port = 6045))`